# Why is my Symfony2 form data being re-arranged?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form which contains an array of entites, rendered as checkboxes:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new BasicListType(), $lists);

class BasicListType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('lists', 'entity', [
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'MyBundle:ListEntity',
            'property' => 'id',
            'property_path' => '[id]',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ]);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'list';
    }
}
```

When I display my form, the rows are not in the same order as the `$lists` I built it with.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {% for list in form.lists %}
        {{ form_row(list) }}
    {% endfor %}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

In fact, they're alphabetised by the `id` property. Why is this happening and more importantly, is there any way I can stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to use the [query_builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) option to construct an custom query, and order the result as you want. Should look something like that:

```
$builder->add('lists', 'entity', [
        'required' => false,
        'class' => 'MyBundle:ListEntity',
        'property' => 'id',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
            $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('l');
                $qb
                    ->select('l')
                    ->orderBy('DESIRED ORDER FIELD', 'ASC OR DESC') // change this!!
                ;
            return $qb;
        }
        'property_path' => '[id]',
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
    ]);
```

You can pass an QueryBuilder Object directly too. Take a look of the docs.